# Recurrence relation: T(n) = T(n/2) + n

Tags: recurrence

Hi there I am trying to solve the following recurrence relation by telescoping but I am stuck on the last step.

```
T(N) = T(N/2) + N              T(1)=0
T(N/2) = T(N/4) + N/2
T(N/4) = T(N/8) + N/4
...
T(2) = T(1) + 2

T(N)= T(1) + N + N/2 + N/4
```

I think the answer is nlogn but I don't know how to interpret the above as nlogn. I can see that I am doing logn steps but where does the n come from?

Answer (score 9):

You have done everything absolutely correctly, but was not able to find a sum. You got: `n + n/2 + n/4 + ...`, which is equal to `n * (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ...)`.

You got a sum of [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), which is equal to `2`. Therefore your sum is `2n`. So the complexity is `O(n)`.

**P.S.** this is not called telescoping. Telescoping in math is when the subsequent terms cancel each other.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is not nlogn but simply n

T(1)=0

T(N) = T(N/2) + N

T(N/2) = T(N/4) + N/2

T(N/4) = T(N/8) + N/4
...
T(2) = T(1) + 2

there are totally log(N) statements in the telescopic expansion

now by telescopic cancellation,

we have T(N) = T(1) + N + N/2 + N/4 + N/8 +.....+ 2

T(1) = 0

T(N) = N + N/2 + ..... + 2

this is a Geometric series with log(n) terms and each term gets halved.

T(N) = N [ 1 - (1/2)^log(N)] / (1/2)

T(N) = 2N[1 - 1/N]

T(N) = 2N - 2

Hence answer is O(N).

Comment: isn't T(1) supposed to be 1?